# regex/linux find command not working as expected

Tags: regex, bash, find

Background: I'm trying to get a total line count of all of the code files (.html|.htm|.php|.js|.css) in my root web dir (recursively) by piping the output of this into `xargs wc -l | grep total`.

```
$ find . -regex '.+\.php'
./inc/db.php
./inc/userauth.php
./index.php
.......... etc.

$ find . -regex '.+\.js'
./inc/jquery-1.7.1.js
./inc/script.js

$ find . -regex '.+\.(php|js)'
(returns nothing)
```

According to [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html),

```
abc(def|xyz) matches abcdef or abcxyz
```

So shouldn't `.+\.(php|js)` match all .php files and .js files?

Comment: You need to escape certain characters that interpreted by the bash shell. You can find a list of those characters here: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Quote.html

Comment: @NickGarvey: I thought those characters would not have any special meaning when used in single quotes.

Comment: The do not have any special meaning when in single quotes. The issue as explained in the answers is that escaping is required for certain characters when not using ERE. By default GNU find uses emacs regex, which requires the escaping.

Comment: Ah you are right, it is regex syntax as mentioned in the answers. My mistake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`find` uses a different style of regex, so you have to write `\(js\|php\)` instead of just `(js|php)`.

Comment: +1. Alternatively, you can instruct `find` to use EREs (which are more like the regexes the OP has in mind) by writing `find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '.+\.(php|js)'`.

Comment: .. and mac needed the option -E for EREs

Answer (score 4):

```
find . -regex '.+\.\(php\|js\)'
```

Escape characters which are special, although it does depend on your shell (so I've been zealous here).